# Raspberry Pi - uv4l WebRTC no audio

Tags: audio, raspberry-pi, webrtc, raspberry-pi2

I've setup up my Raspberry Pi 2 running Wheezy to stream video via uv4l / uv4l-server. I have both a Pi Camera and a USB Microsoft LifeCam HD-5000. I launched uv4l with each driver for each camera and the streaming works fine except for the audio. I'm trying to use my USB webcam as the microphone to stream audio. I read on the uv4l documentation that it picks up the first audio device from "arecord -l" has the audio input and mine prints:

```
**** List of CAPTURE Hardware Devices ****
card 0: HD5000 [Microsoft LifeCam HD-5000], device 0: USB Audio [USB Audio]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
```

I changed my /etc/modprobe.d/alsa-base.conf to match the one on this page: http://www.linux-projects.org/modules/sections/index.php?op=viewarticle&artid=14

I can record audio and play it back by doing:

```
arecord -D plughw:0,0 -d5 test.wav
aplay -D plughw:1,0 test.wav
```

Can someone please point me what I'm missing to be able to stream video and audio via uv4l?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried with or without *PulseAudio*? Try to uninstall it first.

Comment: No, I don't have PulseAudio installed.

Comment: I installed PulseAudio via: "sudo apt-get install pulseaudio", rebooted and checked the uv4l WebRTC stream but it still didn't have any sound. I'm not sure if I'm missing some additional configuration.